# how to show all info and all connected tables with certain object after selecting it in <select>?

Tags: python, html, django

[image]

as you can see on a picture i have select menu where all my so called "video libraries" are shown. The first question is - is there any way to show all data about certain selected "video library" (every video library has its won adress)? And the second question - every video library is connected with couple of different tables (Staff, Films, Ranks etc.) by ForeignKey - how to show data which is connected with certain video library?

```
class VideoLibrary(models.Model):
    shop_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    adress = models.TextField(max_length=264, default='')
```

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    staff_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    nsf = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    living_adress = models.TextField(max_length=264)
    shop_id = models.ForeignKey(VideoLibrary, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def main(request):

    library_list = VideoLibrary.objects.order_by('shop_name')
    adress_list = VideoLibrary.objects.order_by('adress')
    library_dict = {'shop_name': library_list, 'adress' : adress_list}

    return render(request, 'app/main.html', context=library_dict)
```

Comment: If you are talking about showing data, you have to include the view so that we know what you have. When you make your template, you can pass the foreign keys as well so that you can show it in your view.

Comment: @Garberchov i added views.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all in all i found next solution

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import VideoLibrary

def main(request):
    # Fetch all video libraries for the select menu
    library_list = VideoLibrary.objects.order_by('shop_name')
    
    # Check if a specific video library has been selected (e.g., through a query parameter 'library_id')
    selected_library_id = request.GET.get('library_id')
    
    if selected_library_id:
        # Fetch the selected video library details
        selected_library = get_object_or_404(VideoLibrary, pk=selected_library_id)
    else:
        selected_library = None

    context = {
        'library_list': library_list,
        'selected_library': selected_library,
    }

    return render(request, 'app/main.html', context=context)
```

here i just modified my view to handle a selected video library and pass the details to the template. The rest is just classic django